# How to check value in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value here:

```
itemList[i].ul.li.div[1].div[2].p
```

Which is

Updated `n` minutes ago, where `n` can be any number.

How do I check what `n` is in that string?

So I can add it to an if statement, i.e.

```
if( n < 10 ) {
alert("less than 10");
} else {
alert("more than 10")
}
```

Comment: How is `n` put into that string?

Comment: I don't know, but I just get the end result `Updated n numites ago`, where n can be any number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression, for example:

```
var n = "Updated 3 minutes ago".match(/\d+/)[0];
```

**Edited:** Use + to get the value as a number:

```
var n = +"Updated 3 minutes ago".match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`var n = parseInt(itemList[i].ul.li.div[1].div[2].p.innerHTML.split(" ")[1],10);`

or use a regex to find the first number